# Add script codes to Wordpress

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I have the following code that I tried in W3 html editor:

The main goal:
(The code pretty much plays a mp4 video and allows the user to pause/play by clicking on the video screen - no controls are shown) It works fine in a html file.

I want to add this code to my Wordpress website, but the `<script>` section doesn't work. I went to the Wordpress help section to try to incorporate Javascript into my website. Some of the instructions are not obvious to follow. I would really appreciate if somebody could give me a little step-by-step method to make this code below work in Wordpress.

I'm using WordPress Version 4.3.1

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<body>
<! Within the WordPress text editor, there's no need for the <html> & <body> tags >

<video id="myVideo" width="320" height="176" autoplay>
  <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>

<script type="text/javascript"> 

var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo"); 
var isPlaying = true;

vid.onclick = function playVid() {

    if (isPlaying == false){
       myVideo.play(); 
       isPlaying = true;}

    else if (isPlaying == true){
       myVideo.pause(); 
       isPlaying = false; }
} 
</script> 

<! Within the WordPress text editor, there's no need for the <html> & <body> tags >
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: What about the script isn't working?  In Chrome, if you open the JavaScript console (CTRL+SHIFT+i) are there any errors regarding your script?

Comment: "W3 html editor" — In what? Do you mean Amaya? http://www.w3.org/Amaya/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");`

```
 if (isPlaying == false){
       myVideo.play(); 
       isPlaying = true;}

    else if (isPlaying == true){
       myVideo.pause(); 
       isPlaying = false; }
```

your variable is `vid` and you are using `myVideo` to call `play()` and `pause()` which is an id

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your script inside of `window.onload`:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo"); 
    var isPlaying = true;

    vid.onclick = function playVid() {

        if (isPlaying == false) {
           myVideo.play(); 
           isPlaying = true;
        }
        else if (isPlaying == true) {
           myVideo.pause(); 
           isPlaying = false;
       }
    } 
};
```

Comment: Why? That isn't going to help at all. The script appears after the video, so delaying it until the document has finished loading isn't going to help. 
At best this will have no effect, at worst it will overwrite some other function assigned to `onload` (or be overwritten itself).

Comment: I mean there's plenty of things on the page, it's Wordpress. We don't know if something else is modifying the element's `onClick` event.  At the very least it gets `vid` and `isPlaying` out of the global namespace.  As far as troubleshooting goes I say it's worth a shot, but you're probably right it is unlikely this will do anything.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your suggestions

While I was waiting for replies, I have managed to make it work.

If you are building a website using wordpress. You have the option to add a new page/ or post and in your dashboard you can edit it on visual mode or text(html) mode. At first I was running the `<script>` in that text with no success.

What I did is that I went to the Wordpress theme editor (Dashboard menu -> Appearance-> Editor and put my script directly in one of the template pages of my Theme - i.e. the php files that make up your site). I had to play around a little to figure what file does what, but in the end, I figured it out. I pasted my code and it was running fine.

I don't know what's the deal with that wordpress text editor...

Comment: the 'deal' is to stop your writers being able to inject malicious or dangerous JS into blog posts. The way you have done it, will get overwritten if you ever update your theme.

Comment: Thanks Mat for the additional info. I'll keep it in mind